# Varying the src filename in an ansible copy loop based on criteria

Tags: ansible

I have an array of filenames defined in an Ansible playbook which just copies to a host:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    simple_copy:
      - { src: 'file1', dest: 'file1'}
      - { src: 'file2', dest: 'file2'}

  tasks:

    - name: Simple copy files
      copy: 
        src:   "{{ item.src }}"
        dest:  "{{ item.dest }}"
      with_items: "{{simple_copy}}"
```

What I would like to also do is allow for host-unique files to exist.  For example, if the local directory (Let's assume no path differences) contains:

```
file1
file1.uniquehost
file2
```

Then file1.uniquehost should be substituted for file1 (And named file1 on the remote host) since file1.uniquehost exists.  If file1.uniquehost doesn't exist, then file1 should be used without any sort of error.

Since I have hundreds of 'files' (Spanning a complex directory hierarchy), I would like to make this as efficient as possible and avoid adding tasks.  Can this be done in one task in a compact manner?

Comment: are you asking how to replace `file1.uniquehost` with `file1` during the execution time in `copy` module?

Comment: No, the other way around.  If file1.uniquehost exists on the local host, then use that instead of file1.  The name on the remote host would still be file1 even though the source filename was file1.uniquehost.

Comment: Seems to me just do one the simple copy, then do the uniquehost copy, which will overwrite the first copy if the file exists.  Add a `failed_when` so it does not fail if the uniquehost file does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would find [`lookup("fileglob", ...)`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html) helpful in this case, in order to know what local matching files are available before running that `copy:` command

```yaml
- name: sniff out potential overrides on the controller machihne
  set_fact:
    # regrettably, jinja2 does not seem to support dict comprehensions
    simple_copy_overrides: >-
      {%- set result = {} -%}
      {%- for it in simple_copy -%}
      {%-   set _ = result.update({
              it.src: lookup("fileglob", it.src+".*", wantlist=True)
            }) -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
      {{ result }}
- copy:
    src: "{{ simple_copy_overrides[item.src][0] if simple_copy_overrides[item.src] else item.src }}"
    ...
```

and you can of course use more complex logic if you wish to restrict the override to just ending in `"." + inventory_host` or similar, but that's the gist of it

Comment: That worked great.  Thanks for the hint!  I wound up adding a relative path option and a second template fileset for files which need to go through the template module.  But the pattern is exactly the same and set_fact is quicker than running through the simple_copy list twice.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `uniquehost` will match the `inventory_hostname`, and not literally "uniquehost".

So, do the simple copy you have, then another with the `inventory_hostname`:

```
- name: copy default files
  copy: 
    src:   "{{ item.src }}"
    dest:  "{{ item.dest }}"
  with_items: "{{simple_copy}}"

- name: copy host-specific files
  copy: 
    src:   "{{ item.src }}.{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    dest:  "{{ item.dest }}"
  register: result
  failed_when: result.failed and "Could not find or access" not in result.msg
  with_items: "{{simple_copy}}"
```

The second `copy` will overwrite those done in the first, and will not fail in the `uniquehost` file does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I was going to backup to this approach, but decided not to to avoid running through the simple_copy list two times for each host (And having lots of ignored failures).  My uniquehost files are rare in number compared to the bulk of the other files.  The fileglob approach above seemed most applicable.

Comment: If it's that rare, then you can do the first copy and then a `find` for the unique ones.

Comment: That is true.  The lookup(“fileglob”…) is already working well.